# Accessing GitHub pull request details within AWS CodeBuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, sonarqube, continuous-integration, aws-codebuild

In order to add pull request checks from external tools (e.g. SonarCloud) during a CodeBuild job, I need to provide PR details - e.g. the numeric PR key, the base branch, and the compare branch.

I know these are present in the GitHub PR web hook, but I can't access that within CodeBuild.

However CodeBuild is able to post back its own build check, i.e. block the merge if the build fails, so I know that these details must available.

How can I access them from within a CodeBuild 'build context'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kirk,

We added a few more preconfigured environment variables for webhook builds in AWS CodeBuild.

CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_EVENT: The webhook event that triggered the current build.

CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_HEAD_REF: The head reference name of the webhook event that triggered the build. It could be a branch reference or a tag reference.

CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_BASE_REF: The base reference name of the webhook event that triggered the build. It is the branch reference for pull requests.

CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_ACTOR_ACCOUNT_ID: The account id of the user who triggered the webhook event

These are the ones in addition to what was already documented in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-env-vars.html.

Let us know if this doesn't suffice.

Comment: Would be great if these were available in the corresponding CloudWatch event too (pretty please!).  Also, the ability to configure CodeBuild to either check out with Git detached head (as per now), or to clone with the branch (and then to provide the branch information in the CloudWatch event).  So many questions here on SO about how to work around lack of this information.

Answer (score 1):

The variables Subin Mathew explained in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54620045/6716368) are now documented in the linked AWS CodeBuild Documentation. It works great for automated (webhook triggered) build. Unfortunately, the variables seem not to be available if we retry the build from CodeBuild GUI.
It might be possible to utilize GitHub actions instead of the built-in CodeBuild webhook to have more flexibility & advanced workflows