# Obtaining github PR information like description in Codebuild

Tags: github, aws-codebuild

Prequisite: I have read: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-github-pull-request.html

I also read this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-env-vars.html

and this: [Accessing GitHub pull request details within AWS CodeBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54597752/accessing-github-pull-request-details-within-aws-codebuild)

We have several codebuild jobs that trigger on Github pull requests/pull request updates.

As that other question states, far I have seen `$CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_EVENT` which shows something like `PULL_REQUEST_UPDATED` and `CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_TRIGGER` which shows something like `pr/123`

However I am trying to get the actual payload of the webhook event - specifically the title and description of the PR. How can I obtain these?

My fear is that the answer is this information is lost, and that somehow I need to connect to the github API from within the codebuild job in a back and forth. But then they question will be how to authenticate since this is a private repo..

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you ever found an answer to this, but I ran into something similar.  To get other info from GitHub, I used its API.  For authentication, you can add the GitHub token as an environment variable in the buildspec file.  I'd recommend storing it in Parameter Store as a secure string.  Here's a working example file that retrieves the name of the first label on the PR:

```
version: 0.2

env:
  shell: bash
  parameter-store:
      GITHUB_AUTH_TOKEN: GITHUB_AUTH_TOKEN
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
       nodejs: 16
  build:
    commands:
      - |
        PR_NUMBER=$(cut -d "/" -f2 <<< "$CODEBUILD_SOURCE_VERSION")
        echo $PR_NUMBER;
        PR_LABEL_NAME=$(curl --request GET --url "https://api.github.com/repos/<put repo name here>/pulls/$PR_NUMBER" --header "Authorization:Bearer $GITHUB_AUTH_TOKEN" | jq -r '.labels[0].name');
```

If the build is triggered by a PR being created or updated, the CODEBUILD_SOURCE_VERSION var will have a value of "pr/1234" where "1234" is the pull request number.  I'm using `cut` to get the number and drop "pr/".